# Symfony 1.4 sfDoctrinePager: How to set custom SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, doctrine, symfony1

There is an old project written in symfony 1.4

And there is SQL that it is not possible to create using Doctrine. For an example, consider this test SQL:

```
SELECT id,name FROM users
UNION ALL
SELECT id*10 as id,name FROM users

puvlic function getPager(){
$sql = "SELECT id,name FROM users
      UNION ALL
    SELECT id*10 as id,name FROM users";

$pager = new sfDoctrinePager('Users', 10);
    $pager->setQuery($sql);
    $pager->setPage(2);
    $pager->init();
    return $pager;
}
```

It gives the following error:

> Fatal error: __clone method called on non-object in ...

Help please solve the problem.

Comment: `setQuery` takes a `Doctrine_Query` parameter (not an SQL string)

Answer (score 1):

With stock `sfDoctrinePager` class it's not possible to use a custom SQL string. It only accepts an instance of `Doctrine_Query` (see [sfDoctrinePlugin sources](https://github.com/LExpress/symfony1/blob/5d9ba55269219b328d557e7463688ee5cedc3bda/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/pager/sfDoctrinePager.class.php#L152)).

You should construct a `Doctring_Query` object that does exactly what you need (which is likely not possible because of UNION). It requires a query object because pager needs to modify query before executing it (add LIMIT and OFFSET) in a platform-independent way (for example, it's different on MySQL vs. MS-SQL).

If you really need to use custom SQL with `UNION`, the only way to achieve it is to implement your custom `sfDoctrinePager` implementation that accepts SQL and assumes your target DB platform, certain SQL query structure, etc.